# fsockopen returns 'bool(false)' from browser but 'resource(4) of type (stream)' from command line

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, sugarcrm, fsockopen

I cannot send mail in sugarcrm. Suagrcrm sends mail with phpmailer using SMTP. I have identified that the error occurs when an attempt to open a socket connection using fsockopen is made. The call to fsockopen returns boolean (false).
The arguments given to fsockopen are 5 variables containing the following values
`'mail.example.com'(hostname), 25(port), ''(errno), ''(errstr), 10(timeout)`

The error message is
`Code: 10107 Reply: A system call that should never fail has failed.`

The error code is present in microsoft website under 'Windows Sockets Error Codes' and is partly explained as:
`Returned when a provider does not return SUCCESS and does not provide an extended error code. Can indicate a service provider implementation error.`

The issue occurs when I call the script from a broswer. If I execute the script from command line, fsockopen returns a resource.

Program Info:
`Windows XP`
`Apache/2.0.63 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.8 Server`
`PHP Version => 5.2.8`

Can anyone suggest any possible solutions for this issue. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused due to the presence of a firewall in the system used as the web server. It worked fine when I uninstalled the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

When running under windows, try port 587 instead of 25!

Comment: the smtp server is located in another system and it uses port 25

Comment: Then you should enable port 587 also on that machine. Port 25 often gives problems under windows..

Comment: I have tried port 587, but it is also not working. In fact I have tried fsockopen on a number of ips and ports accessible using telnet command and also php through command line, but it is not working when using php as an apache handler. Maybe I am missing out on something in the apache configuration.